# Envió de correo después de insertar datos en php y mysql, PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmailer

ya logre hacer que funcione el PHPMailer para el envió de correos, solo he logrado que funcione con el siguiente código:

Código envió de correo:

```
<?php 

$destinatario = "correo@gmail.com"; 
$asunto = "Este mensaje es de prueba"; 
$cuerpo = ' 
<html> 
<head> 
   <title>Embarques</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Hola!</h1> 
<p> 
<b>se ha registrado un nuevo embarque</b>. 
<br>
Puedes ver los detalles del embarque registrado en el archivo adjunto, o presionando el link anexado.
</p> 
</body> 
</html> 
'; 

//para el envío en formato HTML 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

//dirección del remitente 
$headers .= "From: Administrador <admin@gmail.com>\r\n"; 

mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers) 
?>
```

Eso me funciona perfectamente yo lo ejecuto y me envia los correos sin problemas, pero como puedo hacer para que me envie el correo luego de insertar un registro que viene por medio de un formulario con php.

Este seria mi formulario principal:

```
<form name="formulario" method="POST" action="enviar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Orden nro.: 
<select name="nro_pedido">                        
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br>

Nro. de pedido:
    <input name="po" id="po" type="text"/>

<br>

Cliente:
    <select name="client">                        
             <option value="CLIENTE 1">CLIENTE 1</option>
</select>

<br>

Lote: <select name="nro_lote">
     <option value="EJEMPLO 1">EJEMPLO 1</option>

</select>

Factura: <input name="nro_factu" id="nro_factu" type="text"/>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR"/>

</form>
```

Y luego de alli va al archivo -enviar.php- en ese archivo recibe las variables del formulario anterior y las inserta en la base de datos:

Archivo -enviar.php-

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");
$conexion=conectar();

$nro_pedido=$_POST['nro_pedido'];
$po=$_POST['po'];
$client=$_POST['client'];
$nro_lote=$_POST['nro_lote'];
$nro_factu=$_POST['nro_factu'];

$sql="insert into embarques(nro_pedido,po,client,nro_lote,nro_factu)
values('$nro_pedido','$po','$client','$nro_lote','$nro_factu')";


$ok1=mysqli_query($query,$conexion);
/* PARA EJECUTAR SENTENCIAS EN LA BASE DE DATOS
UTILIZAMOS LA FUNCIÓN mysqli_query(sentencia,conexion)*/

$ok=mysqli_query($sql,$conexion);

if ($ok)
    {
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Correcto!');
        window.location='formulario.php';</script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Error')
    window.location='formulario.php';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Hasta allí todo bien, pero como puedo hacer para meter el -Código envió de correo- allí en el archivo -enviar.php- la idea es que primero inserte los datos y si inserto bien la info que se ejecute el código de envió de correo.

Me dejan saber si la pregunta esta clara o si debo explicar un poco más.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: include_once("enviar-correo.php"); dentro del "if ($ok)" deberia de servir que no? Basicamente, insertas en la BD y el if despliega tu mensaje de "Correcto!" y en el include tendras tu "enviar-correo" (o como se llame tu archivo)

Comment: Hola scorpio408 seria algo asi? if ($ok,include_once("correo.php");) porque me da error en esa misma linea.

Comment: Seria algo asi:
if ($ok)
    {
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Correcto!');
        window.location='formulario.php';</script>";
        include_once('correo.php');
    }

Comment: Estimados buenas noches, he usado el código del amigo que consulta y me funciona correctamente pero quiero personalizarlo un poco, he tratado de incorporarle una imagen como un logo pero cuando envió el mail me llega solo el texto no las imágenes, alguna ayuda por favor